# How the system works when there's no block reward?

Tags: mining-theory

I've came across some articles arguing that it is a good idea to have no block reward at all, but I struggle to understand, how this would work.

I understand that the incentive for miners would be just transaction fees; but how new coins would be created? Even if there would be no new coins as a principle - where any coins come from? From some initial phase of PoW mining/any other initial distribution? If so, doesn't it give to much advantage for the early nodes (and therefore discourage others to join)?

Comment: You should link the articles for context. We can only speculate otherwise about the views expressed in them. In a PoW system, coins are brought into circulation by the block subsidy. If you start at genesis with no subsidy, there would be no coins, and transactions could not exist.

Comment: It would be very helpful to reference the articles ._.

Answer (score 0):

> how new coins would be created? Even if there would be no new coins as a principle - where any coins come from? From some initial phase of PoW mining/any other initial distribution?

Coins would be created the same way as today: from [coin base transactions](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Coinbase). That coin base transactions include fees and rewards, only fees (in a distant future), or only rewards (in the past), makes not much difference.

Comment: If there is no subsidy, there are no coins. I think OP is not asking about Bitcoin, but about a hypothetical system which never had any subsidy.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave this for a while and later probably delete it.